How to extract sub arrays from a larger array with two start and two stop 1-D arrays in Python?
I am looking for a way to vectorize the following code,
# Let cube have shape (N, M, M)
sub_arrays = np.empty(len(cube), 3, 3)
row_start  = ... # Shape (N,) and are integers in range [0, M-2]
row_end    = ... # Shape (N,) and are integers in range [1, M-1]
col_start  = ... # Shape (N,) and are integers in range [0, M-2]
col_end    = ... # Shape (N,) and are integers in range [1, M-1]

# extract sub arrays from cube and put them in sub_arrays
for i in range(len(cube)):
    # Note that the below is extracting a (3, 3) sub array from cube
    sub_arrays[i] = cube[i, row_start[i]:row_end[i], col_start[i]:col_end[i]]

Instead of the loop, I would like to do something like,
sub_arrays = cube[:, row_start:row_end, col_start:col_end]

But this throws the exception,
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Is there instead some valid way to vectorize the loop?

Thaf empty doesn't work, does it?  For each N, you are extracting a (3,3) array? With consistent sizes it is possible to get by with one indexing, but it will take some experimenting to get the details.  For a start it might be easier play with a 2d array, ie a empty((N,9)).

A simpler 1d version has been answered a number of times.   In list comprehension form: [arr[start[i]:end[i]] for i in range(M)].  If the slices vary in size it can't be 'vectorized'.  If they are always the same, we can make an equivalent 2d 'advanced indexing' array (e.g. with linspace).

Linearizing the 2D array in 1D is certainly significantly better for performance since 2D indexing in Numpy tends to be pretty slow. I expect the best pure-Numpy solution to be relatively inefficient. If performance is really critical here, I strongly advise you to write a Cython/Numba code with basic plain loops (and array views). I expect this to be ≥10 times faster than the fastest pure-Numpy code.

I believe this question is a duplicate of the one about Slicing along axis with varying indices. However, since it may not be obvious, I think it's okay to provide the answer in a new context with a somewhat different approach.
From what I can see, you want to extract data from the cube using a sliding window of a fixed size (3×3 in this case), applied to a separate slice along the first axis with varying shifts within the slices.
In contrast to the previously mentioned approach using as_strided, let's use sliding_window_view this time. As a result, we get two additional axes for row_start and col_start, followed by the window dimensions. Note that row_end and col_end appear as if they are equal to the corresponding starting points increased by a fixed square window side, which is 3 in this case:
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

cube_view = sliding_window_view(cube, window_shape=(3, 3), axis=(1, 2))
output = cube_view[range(cube.shape[0]), row_start, col_start].copy()

That's all. But to be sure, let's compare the output with the original code, using test data:
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randint
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

n, m, w = 100, 10, 3     # w - square window size
row_start = randint(m-w+1, size=n)
col_start = randint(m-w+1, size=n)

# Test cube
cube = np.arange(n*m*m).reshape(n, m, m)

# Data to compare with
sub_arrays = np.empty((n, w, w), dtype=cube.dtype)
for i in range(cube.shape[0]):
    sub_arrays[i] = cube[i, row_start[i]:row_start[i]+w, col_start[i]:col_start[i]+w]    
    
# Subarrays from the sliding window view
cube_view = sliding_window_view(cube, window_shape=(w, w), axis=(1, 2))
output = cube_view[range(cube.shape[0]), row_start, col_start].copy()    

# No exceptions should occur at this step
assert np.equal(output, sub_arrays).all()

